# Running MongoDB with Node and nodemon on Ubuntu (18.04.1 LTS) AWS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ubuntu, npm, nodemon

I have Ubuntu (18.04.1 LTS) Linux distribution running on my AWS EC2 Instance.

I have already installed necessary NodeJS and NPM on this system. I have also configured ReactJS to run on this system. Following are the details of NodeJS versions currently available on my system:

```
>node -v
```

Output: `v6.0.0`

```
>nodejs -v
```

Output: `v10.11.0`

```
>npm -v

Output: v6.4.1
```

Now I'm setting up MongoDB on this system. For that, I already installed Mongo and it's working fine. I also installed 'nodemon' in order to start my "server.js" automatically.

But now when I run the command `nodemon` it gives me the following output:

```
ubuntu@/node$ nodemon
[nodemon] 1.18.4
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `nodemon ./server.js`
[nodemon] running an unsupported version of node v6.0.0
[nodemon] nodemon may not work as expected - please consider upgrading to LTS
[nodemon] 1.17.5
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node ./server.js`
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
rs
[nodemon] starting `nodemon ./server.js`
[nodemon] running an unsupported version of node v6.0.0
[nodemon] nodemon may not work as expected - please consider upgrading to LTS
[nodemon] 1.17.5
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node ./server.js`
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

The greatest confusion is that I am not able to figure out how do I upgrade the `node` version only and NOT the `nodejs` version.

Can anybody please help to solve this?

PS: I also want that my current ReactJS setup does not get affected if I upgrade `npm` or `node`

Thanks

Comment: install nvm to change node version https://github.com/creationix/nvm/blob/master/README.md, after installation you can use `nvm install 9` to install node 9

Comment: Thanks. That fixed the issue. However, if I use npm -v command, it's now degraded to version '5.6.0'.